# How to get actual decimal price of tax without round in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How to remove the round function from tax price calculation and get decimal point tax price in cart in Magento 2.

Thanks

Comment: did you solve the issue? can you share us ? Thx Laxman